# Merge [use-state], [use-effect], [use-context] into [react-hooks]

Tags: discussion, synonym-request

I just stumbled upon [use-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-state):

> useState related questions for reactjs hooks api.

[use-context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-context) and [use-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/use-effect)

I feel these should be merged/synonymed into [react-hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/react-hooks), the main feature, which already has a small API surface. I do not have enough rep to suggest it.

Comment: Context API is sufficiently different from hooks in general IMO. How about use-context -> react-context?

Comment: I am inclined to disagree. While these *are* React hooks, each hook has a sufficiently different and specific purpose and use case that I don't see a compelling need to merge them. `useState` is for component state, `useEffect` is component side-effects, and `useContext` for accessing a React context. Is it only these 3 specific hook tags you've issue with, not any of the others?

Comment: Are these the ONLY react hooks in existence? What about `React-Redux`'s `useSelector`?

Comment: `react-*`? `react-use-state`, `react-use-context`, ...

Comment: Re *"...do not have enough rep"*: The [highest threshold is 25,000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292). Don't you mean *power* or *privilege*?